# FacebookTokenError: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-facebook

FacebookTokenError: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
I have the same problem than this man, can somebody help?

[Passport.js TokenError After Deployment to Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634417/passport-js-tokenerror-after-deployment-to-production#new-answer?newreg=0c92bd3734e7499e8758b237c24e10a4)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and finally solved it.

Let's say these are your project links:

- Your website: https://www.example.com
- Facebook login link: https://www.example.com/api/facebook
- Facebook login callback link: https://www.example.com/api/facebook/callback

**Here what I did and works:**

1. Connect to Facebook for Developers
2. Add your domain in "App Domain" (left panel > Settings > Basic > App Domains field): https://www.example.com ("https://" is mandatory)
3. Go to the Settings page of Facebook Login (left panel > PRODUCTS > Facebook Login > Settings)
4. Check to "Yes" the followings: Client OAuth Login, Enforce HTTPS, Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs
5. On the same page, add https://www.example.com/api/facebook and https://www.example.com/api/facebook/callback in "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs"
6. **IMPORTANT**: in your API, make sure your FacebookStrategy callbackURL includes your full callback URL:

```js
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
 clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
 clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
 callbackURL: "https://www.example.com/api/facebook/callback",
},
 (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  process.nextTick(() => {
   console.log('Facebook success:', profile, accessToken, refreshToken);

   return done(null, profile);
  });
 }
));
```

Comment: Just to add, if you have a frontend built in react and a backend build in nodejs, ONLY use the backend domain in all the facebook urls. Make sure you have an SSL cert in your backend server (i.e nginx).